# Unable to have form submit using angularjs and bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I'm trying to do a post and very simply add name and a datetime using a bootstrap datetimepicker. When I select the datetime and hit add nothing happens. However if I type in the field and hit add it will still submit. I've read alot about custom directives for this project, etc. however I just dont seem to be able to get any of them working so I figured I'd just share my code.

Index.cshtml

```
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Create Content Files</h5>
                    </div>
                    <!--Start Form -->
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="addcontentFileform">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">File Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="contentFile.FileName" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Your File Name" required title="Enter your File Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Publish Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" data-ng-model="contentFile.PublishDate" />
                                        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="addcontentFileform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    </span>
                                    <span data-ng-show="editMode">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="addcontentFileform.$invalid" data-ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Start form Buttons -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="closeAddUpdate()">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End form Buttons -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm calling the bootstrap plugins and the controller on the page as expected.

contentFile.controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('contentFileApp', []);
var baseAddress = 'http://localhost:63271/api/ApiContentFile/';
var url = "";

app.factory('contentFileFactory', function ($http) {
return {
    getContentFilesList: function () {
        url = baseAddress + "GetContentFilesList";
        return $http.get(url);
    },
    getContentFile: function (contentFile) {
        url = baseAddress + "GetContentFile/" + contentFile.Id;
        return $http.get(url);
    },
    addContentFile: function (contentFile) {
        url = baseAddress + "Post";
        return $http.post(url, contentFile);
    },
    updateContentFile: function (contentFile) {
        url = baseAddress + "Put/" + contentFile.Id;
        return $http.put(url, contentFile);
    },
    deleteContentFile: function (contentFile) {
        url = baseAddress + "DeleteContentFile/" + contentFile.Id;
        return $http.delete(url);
    }
};
});
app.controller('contentFileController', function PostController($scope, contentFileFactory) {
$scope.contentFiles = [];
$scope.contentFile = null;
$scope.editMode = false;

//get ContentFile
$scope.get = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = this.contentFile;
    $('#viewModal').toggle('show');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('hide');
};

//get all ContentFiles
$scope.getAll = function () {
    contentFileFactory.getContentFilesList().success(function (data) {
        $scope.contentFiles = data
        //$('#fullModal').toggle('show');
        $('#viewModal').toggle('hide');
        $('#contentFileModel').toggle('hide');
        $('#confirmModal').toggle('hide');
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Loading contentFiles! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
    });
};

// add ContentFile
$scope.add = function () {
    var currentContentFile = this.contentFile;
    //if (currentContentFile != null && currentContentFile.FileName != null && currentContentFile.PublishDate && currentContentFile.PhotoURL && currentContentFile.IsOwned && currentContentFile.FileLink && currentContentFile.Description) 
    if (currentContentFile != null && currentContentFile.FileName != null && currentContentFile.PublishDate) {
        contentFileFactory.addContentFile(currentContentFile).success(function (data) {
            $scope.addMode = false;
            currentContentFile.Id = data;
            $scope.contentFiles.push(currentContentFile);

            //reset form
            $scope.contentFile = null;
            // $scope.addcontentFileform.$setPristine(); //for form reset

            $('#contentFileModel').modal('hide');
            $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding contentFile! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        });
    }
};

//edit contentFile
$scope.edit = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = this.contentFile;
    $scope.editMode = true;
    $('#contentFileModel').toggle('show');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('hide');
};

//update contentFile
$scope.update = function () {
    var currentContentFile = this.contentFile;
    contentFileFactory.updateContentFile(currentContentFile).success(function (data) {
        currentContentFile.editMode = false;

        $('#contentFileModel').toggle('hide');
        $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Updating contentFile! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
    });
};

// delete ContentFile
$scope.delete = function () {
    currentContentFile = $scope.contentFile;
    contentFileFactory.deleteContentFile(currentContentFile).success(function (data) {
        $('#confirmModal').toggle('hide');
        $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
        //$('#fullModal').toggle('hide');
        $scope.contentFiles.pop(currentContentFile);

    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Deleting contentFile! " + data.ExceptionMessage;

        $('#confirmModal').toggle('hide');
    });
};

//Model popup events
$scope.showadd = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = null;
    $scope.editMode = false;
    $('#contentFileModel').toggle('show');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('hide');
};

$scope.showedit = function () {
    $('#contentFileModel').toggle('show');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('hide');
};

$scope.showconfirm = function (data) {
    $scope.contentFile = data;
    $('#confirmModal').toggle('show');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('hide');
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = null;
    $('#confirmModal').toggle('hide');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
}

$scope.closeDetails = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = null;
    $('#viewModal').toggle('hide');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
}
$scope.closeAddUpdate = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = null;
    $('#contentFileModel').toggle('hide');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
}
$scope.closeDelete = function () {
    $scope.contentFile = null;
    $('#confirmModal').toggle('hide');
    $('#fullModal').toggle('show');
}

//initialize your contentFiles data
$scope.getAll();
});
```

Sorry about the clutter and messiness, I'm just really curious how to work with all this, and what I might be doing wrong

edit:It seems like the contentFile.PublishDate isnt binding to the model when I click the add button

Comment: do you have any errors? after all... this directive require you to also install momentJS.. if you forgot about it, you may have an error waiting for you at the dev console....

Comment: I have moment added as well and im not getting any console errors, the date is just coming in as undefined in the angular controller

Comment: You have 2 inputs of type `submit` in the same form. I would change those to `type="button"` if you are not submitting the form in the classic HTML way. Otherwise, it's not clear what is really happening when you click those

Comment: It seems like the contentFile.PublishDate isnt binding to the model when I click the add button

Answer (score 1):

I found it! inside your **add** method you got this line:

```
if (currentContentFile != null && 
    currentContentFile.FileName != null && 
    currentContentFile.PublishDate)
```

PROBLEM: before you filling the date field, **currentContentFile.PublishDate** will always be **undefined** and therefore will keep blocking you from setting a value at the first time... that is also why you "fixed" it by manually inserting a value

in short - replace the above statement with:

```
if (currentContentFile != null && 
    currentContentFile.FileName != null)
```

Comment: That field works however, if I type the date in instead of just selecting it from the datepicker it works, for some reason though selecting the date puts in the date but then when I try to add it that way the add button does nothing as if the value from the datepicker that gets entered in the textbox isnt binding unless its typed in